# Does the local Bertini theorem in mixed characteristic imply the global Bertini theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring with fraction field $K$ and residue field $k$. Assume that the characteristic of $K$ is $0$ and of $k$ is $p>0$. Let $\pi:X \to \mbox{Spec}(R)$ be a flat, projective morphism with $X$ a regular scheme. Is it true that a general hypersurface of $H_X$ is a regular scheme, flat over $\mbox{Spec}(R)$?

If I understand correctly, this is true "locally" by a result of Flenner proven in [Die Sätze von Bertini für lokale Ringe](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01351596).

Comment: Note that this type of question is much easier if you replace '$X$ a regular scheme' by '$\pi$ a smooth morphism', because the latter is well-behaved in families. The statement for $\pi$ smooth follows from the case over $\operatorname{Spec} k$, because the smooth locus is open.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn The family $\pi$ is question is not smooth.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [arxiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05877), especially Corollary 5.6